# Variable length lookahead/behind regex when you don't know exactly what you're matching (python)

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have some transcriptions that unfortunately contain lots of occurrences of words separated by a period but no space (ie word.word).

Is there a way to use regex to separate these, but leave other words like decimals and abbreviations such as U.K. or U.S.A alone? I'm planning to tokenize the text, and so i want the word.word occurrences to be counted as separate words, but I don't want to mess up abbreviations/decimals/any other places where the period is part of the word. Since I would want to replace these specific word.word periods with a space but leave all others alone (or at least not replace them with a space because then it would break up the abbreviation), my first thought was something like this:

`text = re.sub("(?<!\d){2,}\.(?!\d){2,}", " ", text)`

look for periods that are surrounded by at least two or more not-digits, and then just replace the period with a space. But it seems that variable length lookbehind/lookahead isn't really a thing you can do. I've tested this out in some regex testers and it still matches the letter abbreviations above, although it does not match decimals.

Is there another way to write what I've thought about or another way to approach this? I've gotten somewhat mentally stuck in this solution and I can't find another way that will do close to what I'm looking to do - can it even be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Let's say you want to split only length>1 words by periods? e.g `"i.would.like.to.visit.the.U.S.A"` will be `["i", "would", "like", "to", "visit", "the", "U.S.A"]`. Right? what about the word "a"? [a noun]. So you only want to keep upper-case abbrevations together? [U.S.A but not u.s.a]

Comment: Case doesn't matter much - U.S.A should be kept together but p.m. should also be kept if it's ever written that way. The length>1 on both sides splitting is what I'm looking to accomplish. Thankfully there don't seem to be any cases we've come across where it's a word and then an abbreviation, it's more just something probably happened with sentence boundaries getting smushed together.

Comment: Do i **have** to use regex?

Comment: If there's another way to approach this please do let me know - it doesn't have to be regex, that's just where I started out because it seemed like the easiest way to apply the changes to large amounts of transcripts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so :D
i have written this code, which i have given it the string `"i.would.like.to.visit.the.U.S.A.or.the.u.k.while.i.am.eating.a.banana.b"` (the b is there for a purpose, to make sure it doesn't delete one letters for no reason), and the output was:
`['i', 'would', 'like', 'to', 'visit', 'the', 'USA', 'or', 'the', 'uk', 'while', 'i', 'am', 'eating', 'a', 'banana', 'b']`.

The code is:

```py
text = "i.would.like.to.visit.the.U.S.A.or.the.u.k.while.i.am.eating.a.banana.b"


def split(string: str):
    string = string.split(".")
    length = len(string) - 1
    obj = enumerate(string)
    together = []
    for index, word in obj:
        sub = []
        if index and len(word) == 1 and index < length:
            idx = index
            while len(string[idx]) == 1:
                sub.append((string[idx], idx))
                idx += 1
                next(obj)
        together.append(sub)
    if together:
        deleted = 0
        for sub in together:
            if len(sub) > 1:
                string[sub[0][1] - deleted:sub[-1][1] + 1 - deleted] = ["".join(x[0] for x in sub)]
                deleted += len(sub) - 1

    return string


print(split(text))
```

You can edit the section `"".join(x[0] for x in sub)` to `".".join(x[0] for x in sub)` in order to keep the dots, (U.S.A instead of USA)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to add space if both sides are two or more characters the following is what you are looking for.

`text = re.sub(r"([^\d.]{2})\.([^\d.]{2})", r"\1. \2", text)`

Example:

`"This sentence ends.The following is an abbreviation A.B.C."` becomes

`"This sentence ends. The following is an abbreviation A.B.C."`